# Classic Knight Tour Problem , 1 cell unvisited

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, puzzle, knights-tour

I am trying to solve Knight's tour using Backtracking, where Knight has to visit all the cells
Anyhow I am always getting 1 cell unvisited.
Example for 4x4 chessBoard size, I am getting output as:

1 8 13 10

14 11 4 7

5  2 9 12

0 15 6 3

As you can see, that Left Bottom most cell is unvisited always. How can I fix it so it visits all cells.
Below is my code:

```
import sys
from pandas import *
class knightTour:

    xMoves = [2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2] 
    yMoves = [1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1] 

    def KT(self,size):
        self.size=size
        visited = [[0 for i in range(size) ]for i in range(size)]

        visited[0][0]=1

        if(self.solveKT(visited,2,0,0)):
            self.printSolution(visited)
        else:
            print("No solution Found")
    
    def solveKT(self,visited,moveCount,x,y):
        if(moveCount == self.size**2):
            return True
        
        for i in range(8):
            nextX= x+self.xMoves[i]
            nextY= y+self.yMoves[i]



            if self.isValidMove(visited,nextX,nextY):
                
                visited[nextX][nextY] = moveCount

                if(self.solveKT(visited,moveCount+1,nextX,nextY)):
                    return True
                

                visited[nextX][nextY]=0
            
        return False

    def isValidMove(self,visited,x,y):
        n=len(visited)
        if x >= 0 and y >= 0 and x < n and y < n and visited[x][y]==0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        
    def printSolution(self,visited):
        print(DataFrame(visited))
        
        # for i in range(len(visited)):
        #     print(visited[i])
        # print("\n")

obj=knightTour()
obj.KT(4)
```

Comment: No surprise. [There is no](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour#Existence) knight tour on a 4*x board, to begin with. Your code seems correct.

Comment: But the code is leaving Bottom Left unvisited or 0 even for 8x8.. Any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this part of your code:

```
if(moveCount == self.size**2+1):
          return True
```

Also, there is no solution for 4x4 board starting at position [0][0], but this code will work for 8x8 board.

Comment: Hi @Rajath Sharma. I tried this, but it results in a ListIndexOutOfRange error.

Comment: Can you post your complete error. Also, what size of board you are trying with ?

Comment: Hi Rajath, the ListIndexError was for 4x4, but got answer for 8x8.. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Any idea why it gives ListIndexOutOfBounds error for 4x4 but not 8x8 . 
PS: I now know Knight's tour to visit all the cells is not possible using 4x4 board. Still why does it not throw error for 4x4? Just curious. Your answer helped a lot..Thanks!!

Comment: Can you post your complete error, as I am not getting error for 4 x4 at my end.